# Python Return Unpacked Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to return an unpacked dictionary based on some condition:

```
def process(batch, cond):
  if(cond):
    return **batch
  else
    return batch

input = process(batch, cond)
output = model(input)
```

However, I get a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` because of the `return **batch` line.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by an 'unpacked dictionary'.  Can you provide an example of what the value of `batch` is?  Also, tell us what the desired value of `input` is.

Comment: @Bill: by unpacking, please check the section titled "** is used for dictionaries" in this link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/

Comment: [These docs](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/dict_unpack.html) give a better description because they explicitly mention that the unpacking operator is only for use in unpacking function arguments: `function(**dict)`

Comment: Interesting that the [official Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments) refer to this as 'argument unpacking'. 'Dictionary unpacking' could perhaps refer to this procedure: `key1, key2, key3 = batch` although this is much rarer and less useful than tuple unpacking.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You need to extract your unpack logic to outside of `process`:

```
def process(batch):
    return batch

input = process(batch)
if cond:
    output = model(**input)
else:
    output = model(input)
```

If you really need `process`, also pass `model` to it:

```
def process(batch, model, cond):
    input = process(batch)
    if cond:
        return model(**input)
    return model(input)

output = process(batch, model, cond)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you could achieve what you want like this:

```
def process(batch, cond):
  if(cond):
    kwargs = batch
  else:
    kwargs = {'a': batch}
  return kwargs

def model(a=0, b=0, c=0):
  print(a + b + c)

batch = {'a': 100, 'b': 101, 'c': 102}
cond = True
kwargs = process(batch, cond)
model(**kwargs)
# Output: 303

batch = 100
cond = False
kwargs = process(batch, cond)
model(**kwargs)
# Output: 100
```